# Assigning value to the variable in Qt

Tags: python, qt

Here is the converted .ui of Qt to the .py:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
  _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_NewWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, NewWindow):
    NewWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("NewWindow"))
    NewWindow.resize(439, 225)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(NewWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 140, 99, 27))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 365, 89))
    self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
    self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
    NewWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(NewWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 439, 25))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    NewWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(NewWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    NewWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(NewWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NewWindow)

  def retranslateUi(self, NewWindow):
    NewWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "MainWindow",    None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Exit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "A = ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.lineEdit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "B = ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Add", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Answer  : ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  NewWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_NewWindow()
  ui.setupUi(NewWindow)
  NewWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After running the above python program it shows the window as:
[image]

But I have to assign the value from the line edit to the variable A and B so I can add them as:

```
sum = A + B
```

and I have show this value `sum` in the label Answer when we clicked on push button "Add" in above window, so please suggest proper change in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a news action (`ad_values` in this case). Then, you need to connect this action to the Buttons signal (`clicked` for example). After the signal emits (i.e. the button is clicked), the actions reads the values from `lineEdit` and `lineEdit_2`, adds them up and set's the text of the `label_2`-widget (you might convert the values to int before [see the other answer for a simple implementation])

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import Slot

try:
  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
  _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_NewWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, NewWindow):
    NewWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("NewWindow"))
    NewWindow.resize(439, 225)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(NewWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 140, 99, 27))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 365, 89))
    self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
    self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
    #self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4)
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
    NewWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(NewWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 439, 25))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    NewWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(NewWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    NewWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(NewWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NewWindow)

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_values)

  def retranslateUi(self, NewWindow):
    NewWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "MainWindow",    None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Exit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "A = ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.lineEdit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "B = ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Add", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "Answer  : ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("NewWindow", "0.0", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

  @Slot()
  def add_values(self):
      # you should convert the values to integers for a less error-prone code
      summed = float(self.lineEdit.text()) + float(self.lineEdit_2.text())
      self.label_2.setText(str(summed))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  NewWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_NewWindow()
  ui.setupUi(NewWindow)
  NewWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I´m using PySide, but it should work with PyQT as well.

Comment: I tried your above modified code using PyQt, but it is adding the text only. Means is A=20 and B=25 then answer is giving as 2025 instead of 45.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just combine Nejat`s solution with mine, this should work.  See the corrections i made.

Comment: hey, if you know please tell me. I have converted the .ui file to .py which is the program of opening a new window by clicking a pushbutton. But thing is that the program is working on Qt only but when i try to run the converted .py code the first main window is opening but nothing is happening after clicking the push button, means the another window is not opening.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should ask this one in another question, providing the full code

Comment: @ dorvak : this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748225/the-converted-py-file-of-qt-is-not-working-for-opening-new-window please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
def sum(self):
  summed = float(self.lineEdit.text()) + float(self.lineEdit_2.text())
  self.label_2.setText(str(summed))
```